# If one male A and one female B cannot be in the same committee, how many ways can choose?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question for counting, I work through but not sure for the ii and iii. As for part (ii) and (iii), I did it but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

A class consists of 15 men and 17 women. Find the number of ways that the people in the class can arrange themselves in the following cases.
(i) How many groups can be chosen from this class which consists of 7 men and 10 women?

Answer: C(15,7) * C(17,10) = 125147880

(ii)If two students have to be in the same group, how many groups of 12 students can be formed from this class?

Answer: 1 x C(30,10) + C(30,12) =

(iii) If one male A and one female B cannot be in the same committee, how many ways can a committee consisting of 4 men and 4 women be chosen from the class?

Answer:
A committee consisting of 4 men and 4 women:

C(15,4) * C(17,4) = 3248700

From 3248700 subtract the cases where that male A and female B in the same committee. In those case we choose 3 men from the other 14 and 3 women from the other 16, so the number must subtract is:

C(14,3) * C(16,3) =364 * 560 = 203840
=> 3248700 - 203840 = 3044860

Comment: Part (ii): why you plus C(30,12)?

Comment: cause those groups which involve two people + those groups which not involve the two people, something wrong here, I am not sure, so need help

Comment: Keep the two  students as one student and you will have 31 now, now select 12 from 31 and another 12 from (31-12) for Part II

Comment: For the third part you are right

Comment: Thanks, Satish, but I do still not understand part ii. Could you give me more explanation for that?

Comment: If two students have to be in the same group, club them as one.  Now the total number of students is 31 and two groups can be formed of size 12.  Intitally select 12 studens from the 31 and then select another 12 from the remaining 19 students.  Hence the answer is ${31\choose12}.{19\choose12}$

Answer (score 0):

If two students have to be in the same group, club them as one.  Now the total number of students is 31 and two groups can be formed of size 12.  Intitally select 12 studens from the 31 and then select another 12 from the remaining 19 students.  Hence the answer is ${31\choose12}.{19\choose12}$